# How can I group fancybox when using it on single elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm looping trough each element so I can change the `href` value, but with this, I can't group the images. `rel` is not working.

```
[].forEach.call(gallery_images_thumbnails_list.querySelectorAll('.category'), function(element){
    $(element).fancybox({
        href: element.getAttribute('data-image'),
        rel: "fancybox"
    });
});
```

How can I group them if I do it like this? If not, is it possible to have fancybox on `.category` and at the same time set the `href` for each element?

Comment: can you reproduce the error in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

If `$(element)` is an *anchor* (`<a>` tag), try this instead

```
[].forEach.call(gallery_images_thumbnails_list.querySelectorAll('.category'), function (element) {
    $(element).attr("rel", "fancybox").fancybox({
        href: element.getAttribute('data-image')
    });
});
```

because, when you do

```
$(element).fancybox({
    //API options
});
```

... the plugin is expecting **[valid](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)** API options and `rel` is not one of them.

---

On the other hand, if `$(element)` is an `<img>` tag (because I see you are *querying* thumbnails), then you rather try

```
[].forEach.call(gallery_images_thumbnails_list.querySelectorAll('.category'), function (element) {
    $(element).wrap($("<a />", {
        href: element.getAttribute('data-image'),
        rel: "fancybox",
        "class": "fancybox"
    }));
});
```

**Notice** *class* requires to be in quotes because it's a *reserved* javascript word

The code above still may need a fancybox initialization code like

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    // API options
});
```